# ST-GCN: graph convolution operator in Geometry-Aware Interaction Network (GAIN)

Tags: pytorch, graph-neural-networks, graphs, gnn

I need help implementing the model in this [paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2023W/Biometrics/papers/Chang_A_Closer_Look_at_Geometric_Temporal_Dynamics_for_Face_Anti-Spoofing_CVPRW_2023_paper.pdf):

They have adopted spatio-temporal graph convolution operator in ST-GCN [section 3.1.2]. I've found there is popular libraries available for GCN: [pytorch_geometric](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric) and [torch_geometric_temporal](https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/pytorch_geometric_temporal), but I'm new to the graph NNs. [image]

This is the overal network architecture in the paper, and I'm tring to implement the geometric feature part. For the dense landmark detection I'll be using mediapipe's FaceMesh landmarks (because the dense landmark detection model used in the paper is not available publicly).

Currently what I've written is as below:

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Linear
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.typing import Adj, OptTensor


class GAIN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels: int,
        hidden_channels: int,
        out_channels: int,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self._graph_conv_1 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=in_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self._graph_conv_2 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=hidden_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self._graph_conv_3 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=hidden_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self._graph_conv_4 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=hidden_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self._graph_conv_5 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=hidden_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self._graph_conv_6 = GCNConv(
            in_channels=hidden_channels,
            out_channels=hidden_channels,
        )
        self.linear = Linear(hidden_channels, out_channels)


    def forward(
        self, 
        x: torch.FloatTensor,
        edge_index: Adj,
        edge_weight: OptTensor = None
    ):
        x = self._graph_conv_1(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self._graph_conv_2(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self._graph_conv_3(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self._graph_conv_4(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self._graph_conv_5(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self._graph_conv_6(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x

def train_gcn():
    # I'm not sure what should be hidden and out channels, just setting 64 and 256. 
    # I guess in channel should be 2 because node feateure is (x, y) coordinate.
    model = GAIN(in_channels=2, hidden_channels=64, out_channels=256)

    criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001, lr=0.1)

    data = None # I don't know

    # Training loop
    for epoch in range(65):
        # Clear gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Forward pass
        y_hat = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
        # Calculate loss function
        loss = criterion(y_hat, data.y)
        # Calculate accuracy
        acc = accuracy(y_hat.argmax(dim=1), data.y)
        # Compute gradients
        loss.backward()
        # Tune parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        # Print metrics every 10 epochs
        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch {epoch:>3} | Loss: {loss:.2f} | Acc: {acc*100:.2f}%')
```

What I'm struggling with are:

- I don't know how to interpret formula (3) in the code.
- How to construct input X and edge matrices.
- Overall am I implementing it correctly?

Please help me implement it.

Comment: 'Please help me implement it' is not a question that can be answered on this forum. You will need to ask specific questions that you struggle with when implementing it. What do you not understand about the paper that makes it difficult for you to implement it?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn I've updated the question